# Using the second database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, codeigniter, codeigniter-2

I'm trying to query from my second database in Codeigniter, so In my database configuration I have the following:

```
$active_group = 'default';
$active_record = TRUE;

$db['default']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['default']['username'] = 'root';
$db['default']['password'] = '';
$db['default']['database'] = 'gallery';
$db['default']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['default']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['default']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['default']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['default']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['default']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['default']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['default']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['default']['stricton'] = FALSE;

$db['tc']['hostname'] = 'localhost';
$db['tc']['username'] = 'root';
$db['tc']['password'] = '';
$db['tc']['database'] = 'timecard';
$db['tc']['dbdriver'] = 'mysql';
$db['tc']['dbprefix'] = '';
$db['tc']['pconnect'] = TRUE;
$db['tc']['db_debug'] = TRUE;
$db['tc']['cache_on'] = FALSE;
$db['tc']['cachedir'] = '';
$db['tc']['char_set'] = 'utf8';
$db['tc']['dbcollat'] = 'utf8_general_ci';
$db['tc']['swap_pre'] = '';
$db['tc']['autoinit'] = TRUE;
$db['tc']['stricton'] = FALSE;
```

and in my model method I have the following code:

```
    public function getAll() 
    {
             $tc = $this->load->database('tc', TRUE);    
             $sql = "SELECT username, MIN(timeIn) 
                     FROM timecard2.tc_timecard
                     GROUP BY userid  having  MIN(timeIn) >? and 
                     MIN(timeIN)<? order by MiN(timeIN);";                                    
            $q=$tc->query($sql,'2013-01-08','2013-01-23');                                    
            if ($q->num_rows() > 0)
            {
                foreach ($q->result() as $row) {
                    $data[] = $row;
                 }
                 return $data;
            }
     }
```

but it does not work! is it the right way to query the second database?

If you need more clarification please let me know which part you need more clarifiocation.

**EDITED:**
Just figured out it works fine with one ? (parameter)!
It works for the following code:

```
    $sql = "SELECT username, MIN(timeIn) 
            FROM tc_timecard
            GROUP BY userid  having  
            MIN(timeIn) > ? and MIN(timeIN) < '2013-01-23' 
            order by MiN(timeIN);";                        

    $q=$tc->query($sql,'2013-01-08');
```

Do you have any clue why it does not get the second parameter?

Thanks

Comment: I figured it out; I needed to pass an array for parameters!

Answer (score 1):

Per codeigniter's documentation: https://www.codeigniter.com/user_guide/database/connecting.html

```
$tc = $this->load->database($db['tc'], TRUE);
```

Comment: I figured out that second database is not a big deal here; just I cannot pass the second parameter! Please see my edit at the very end of my question that I have just added! Do you have any clues why it does not pass the second parameter?

Comment: second parameter should be an array, example: $tc->query($sql,array('2013-01-08','2013-01-09'));